# Find the number of distinct roots for polynomial of degree 3

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

Can anyone guide me on how to find the number of distinct roots for a given polynomial of degree $3$, what is the best approach?

I have this example $$ f(x)=-{x}^{3}+3x-y $$ where y is a real number, for what $y$ ,does $f(x)$ has three distinct real roots? How to solve this kind of question?Please provide a general approach and then relating specifically to this question.

Thank you so much!

Comment: distinct *real* roots or would you also accept complex roots?

Comment: @Hagen von Eitzen distinct

Comment: You mean distinct *real*?

Answer (score 4):

One method is to compute the discriminant, which is by definition the product of differences among the roots, hence is zero iff at least one root is a multiple root.

Another approach is to note that a multiple root is a common root of $f$ and $f'$. So by polynomial division you may obtain some insights.
Here, $f(x)=-x^3+3x-y$ and $f'(x)=-3x^2+3$, so a common root of $f$ and $f'$ is also a root of
$$ f(x)-\frac x3f'(x)=2x-y.$$
Hence a multiple root, if it exists, occurs at $x=\frac12y$. Now check for which $y$ is $f(\frac12y)=0$ - or simpler: $f'(\frac12y)=0$? This is of course the case iff $y=\pm 2$. In all other cases the three (possibly complex) roots of $f$ are distict.

But can the roots be *real* and distinct? This can be checked differently: We find the two extrema $\pm1$ of the cubic (i.e., roots of $f'$) and check if $f(+1)$ and $f(-1)$ have different signs. As $f(1)=2-y$ and $f(-1)=-2-y$ we obtain the condition $-2<y<2$.

Comment: why "a multiple root is a common root of f and f' "?

Comment: could you please explain in more mathematical way, like the steps or graphs so that I can understand better ?thx

Answer (score 1):

For an equation of the form $x3+px+q=0$, the number of real roots is $3$ if the discriminant $\Delta=-4p^3-27q^2$ is positive.

Here this condition simplifies to $\,27(y^2-4)<0$, i. e.
$$\lvert y\rvert <2.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:
The equation
$$
x^3+Bx^2+Cx+D=0
$$has three distict real roots if:

$$
\Delta=P^3+Q^2<0
$$

where:
$$
P=\dfrac{3C-B^2}{9} \qquad Q=\dfrac{2B^3-9BC+27D}{54}
$$